# How to change the value in char *array[]?

Tags: arrays, c, syntax

I have an array(Array) and the value define as char array (LIST) in another .h file.

```c
char *Array[]= { "something1", "something2", "something3" };
```

LIST is defined in .h file.

```c
#define LIST {“a”, “b”, “c”}
```

If I would like to change all values in Array to be LIST. What should I do?

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Do you really have `LIST` defined like that (instead of a `char*[]`)? That's a very weird way to define it.

Comment: It's three backtick characters, or four spaces for indentation. You were using some other kind of quotes that don't match.

Comment: The correct answer is to get rid of the LIST macro and define a second array instead. Also, these arrays should be `const char* array[]`.

Comment: You *urgently* need to fix your quotes. These are “smart quotes” that do not belong in code. These can cause considerable problems when debugging because they are not syntactically valid but look virtually identical in some fonts. Use a code editor, not a word processor, to edit code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `LIST` doesn't exist as anything you can copy, you need to instantiate it somehow first, like:

```c
char* list[] = LIST;
```

Then you need to copy it over, but you have no idea how big it is, so you're sort of stuck again.

What would be better is:

```c
#define LIST {"a" "b", "c", NULL}
```

Where now you can at least tell where that stops.

You could also define a `global` const, or a `static` variable, depending on exactly how this is used, and how often. A `#define` is really the worst tool for this job even if it can be done.

As for assignment, assuming the lists are the same size:

```c
char** a = &array[0];

for (char** p = &list[0]; *p; ++p, ++array) {
  *array = *p;
}
```

Where that will spin through until it hits the `NULL` terminator.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @tadman's answer, you could use compound literals if you turn `char *Array[]` into `char **Array`.

Here's an example:

```
#define LIST {"a", "b", "c"};

int main(void)
{
  char **Array = (char *[3]) {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
  Array = (char *[3]) LIST;
}
```

Compound literals were introduced in the C99 standard, so if you're working with an older version, don't try using this. However, if you choose to turn the `LIST` macro into, say, a global array, a compound literal wouldn't work since it requires you to use a brace-enclosed initializer.